# HTML pages are not getting updated

Tags: html, caching, browser, meta

I am encountering strange problem while developing a static website for my customer. Every time when I push my changes to the server on my hosting (through to FTP to usuall `public_html` folder), my customer needs to delete cache of the browser in order to see new changes that I put there. This also happens on other computers with exception of my own. This is `head` of all my pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>STINGPRO s.r.o.</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

So should I forbid caching in `meta` header like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers) or problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: Check the response headers with firebug etc. to see how pages are cached (Cache-Control, Expires) you can change cache control with .htaccess file (if apache server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is most likely sending the Cache-Control and Expires headers when serving up the page and telling the browser not to check for the content. If you cannot control the request headers, you can manually force the reload. See this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers) for details on turning off caching.

Comment: Is there a way how to disable it directly on the server?I am using Apache